# Disconnections during login based on IP or how?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, vpn, proxy

I have issues (it seems many people have) to connect to PlayStation site, since when trying to login usually gives server connection error. It seems is a security feature of that website. As they mention in [a Google forum post here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/40314654/playstation-network-can-t-let-me-sign-in-through-latest-google-chrome-browser) and in other sites too, that they have tried using a VPN or changing options in Chrome like adding to accepted cookies the Sony URL or turning OFF “Preload pages for faster loading,” clearing browser cache, etc but any of that actions seem to provide a permanent fix.

I’ve noticed that using a VPN something works trying different locations, but is not a thing like I get the server connection error and after trying a different location on VPN would fix it. Sometimes doesn’t work simply changing location, only allows the access again waiting for several minutes or hours.

Then, from my lack of knowledge I ask if this could be a security system that blocks the login sending "server connection error" based on IP used, or based in MAC Address? I Don’t know how to avoid this error to happen  repeatedly.

For example, connected with home’s WiFi I received the error, then I tried to change IP with a VPN changing several locations and doesn’t work. Immediately after that, I tried connecting to internet using cellphone’s WiFi and it works at the first attempt and that is basically the same as using a VPN, that is change IP used, but with VPN didn’t work.

Comment: what is the precise error? "server connection error" is not a specific error. do you see anything like "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT", or an error code like 500, 403, etc? are you using HTTPS in your url in the browser?

Comment: Yes, the URL has https. The error is `A connection to the server could not be established.
(18.c93a2217.1810986464.46709b77)` The part between parentheses changes each time but is similar. [This is the URL](https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/id/management/#/p/security/) for anyone that wants to help could create an account an give a try. The first login fine, but if you try several times you´ll see the error

Comment: so that looks like its not a network or browser error, but something coming from a front-end load balancer (likely with a WAF). That generally means that only Sony could help you. you should be able to contact their support, and give them that long alphanumeric string so they can look up what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your help. I supposed that was not a browser side issue since happens with others browsers. what is weird for me is that should work with a VPN since it uses a different IP, doesn´t work.

Comment: well, organizations block what they want to block, and VPNs are often "misused" from the corporate perspective, and often appear on blocklists. after they got hacked through a PS3 15 or whatever years ago, they have been very security orriented.